# How to individually check off checkboxes with the same name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a list of checkboxes set up, where I have certain `<div>`'s show up depending on which checkboxes the user selects.

The list of checkboxes is the following code:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
   <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, item.name)" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</li>
```

And the code to determine which checkbox is checked off, based on the name, is the following:

```
      isSelect(fruit: string) {
    return this.items.find(x => x.checked && x.name == fruit) != null
  }

  get isAppleSelected() {
    return this.isSelect("Apple")
  }
```

The list of items can have multiple checkboxes with the same name. For example, multiple checkboxes named "Apple".

The problem I am having is when the user checks off one checkbox named "Apple", it checks off **ALL** the checkboxes named "Apple".

How would I solve this and allow the user to check off each "Apple" checkbox individually? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You must provide an unique ID for each checkboxes like :

```
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
       <mat-checkbox [id]="item.id" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event, item.name)" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the code you provided but it still doesn't work. Is there other code I need to add?

Comment: my answer should work .can u create stackblitz demo ?